# Efficiency of uniqueness validation in Active Record Rails

Tags: performance, activerecord, processing-efficiency, validates-uniqueness-of

Which is more efficient while creating records with unique values for a column in rails 
**Placing uniqueness validation vs finding if record exists with same value** and create based on the existence.

Which is more **efficient** in terms of coding and **performance**.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A database uniqueness constraint will give you the highest performance.

At the application level, whether you are using `validates_uniqueness_of` or manually finding if the record exists, the performance will basically be the same.  In fact, that is exactly how it is implemented in Rails: https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/0d73d6e7b6dd1900f105397460b777ef6c03d3b6/activerecord/lib/active_record/validations/uniqueness.rb#L33